# How to show Loader in Flutter Map

Tags: flutter

I am using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) package. When I show on screen for a second it shows a grey screen. I want to show the loader here. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
SizedBox(
        height: 130,
        child: FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
            center: LatLng(
              widget.latitude,
              widget.longitude,
            ),
            zoom: 13.0,
          ),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
              userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
            ),
            MarkerLayer(
              markers: [
                Marker(
                  width: 30.0,
                  height: 30.0,
                  point: LatLng(
                    widget.latitude,
                    widget.longitude,
                  ),
                  builder: (ctx) => Container(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_pin,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I am using the version: `flutter_map: ^4.0.0`